# I asked my question, yet it was closed and then deleted

Tags: discussion

I asked following question:

[games - How to do "Android Party Play" with "Real Racing 3"? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120857/how-to-do-android-party-play-with-real-racing-3)

apparently it wasn't clear enough, so it was closed

> closed as unclear what you're asking by Matthew Read♦ Aug 31 at 21:55
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the
>   rules in the help center, please edit your question.

I then went ahead and *updated* my question by trying to make it *clear* on what exactly I was asking, then I clicked `reopen`, after while instead of my question being reopen or even commented, my question was `deleted`.

Comment: Closed questions are automatically deleted after a period of time, which was the case here. It looks like your question was put into the re-open queue but 3 users decided it should remain closed. For the purposes of discussion, I have undeleted the question, so that others will be able to have the complete context.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in [eldarerathis' comment](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/i-asked-my-question-yet-it-was-closed-and-then-deleted#comment4579_2010),

> Closed questions are automatically deleted after a period of time, which was the case here. It looks like your question was put into the re-open queue but 3 users decided it should remain closed.

Well, to be exact, not *all closed questions* will be deleted. The criteria is listed on [a post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/241919),

> Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:
>
> - Closed more than 9 days ago
> - Not closed as a duplicate
> - Score <= 0
> - Not locked
> - No answers with a score > 0
> - No accepted answer
> - No pending reopen votes
> - No edits in the past 9 days

And your post fulfilled all the criteria (the reopen votes were expired).

Next, you might be wondering why even after you've updated the question to make it clear, the reviewers decided it should remain closed (I believe I wasn't one of them, this is the first time I read your question). Of course I can't tell their thought, but in my opinion, the updated revision was still *a bit* too broad: you asked 2 questions in 1 post.

Asking multiple questions in a single post is not prohibited, if all of them are strictly related. However, in your case, you asked 2 questions unrelated *to each other*:

1. Connecting Android to TV
2. Connecting PS3 controller to Android

The first one is a dupe of [Is it possible to connect a Android phone display to a TV or PC Monitor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37043/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-android-phone-display-to-a-tv-or-pc-monitor). The second one hasn't been asked yet. You could ask that instead, but focus on the issue and explain what you have tried to prevent us suggesting the same things that you've actually done (help us to help yourself).