# deleted by Community / RemoveDeadQuestions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

I asked following questions:

- [6.0 marshmallow - partial? wakelock detector without root - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131894/partial-wakelock-detector-without-root)
- [bluetooth - Nexus 6p - kernel wakelock - bluesleep - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131990/nexus-6p-kernel-wakelock-bluesleep)

which later outcome following issue to filed:

[Issue 207700 - android - Partial Wakelock - Android System *backup* = NO deepsleep/doze mode - Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207700)

As of today that issue generated over 215 comments and one of this question I finally figure out the answer which I wanted to share with rest of community but due to `deleted by Community` I cannot! both of my questions generated over 1000 views, so while it was labeled as `RemoveDeadQuestions` it is still pretty much alive and if question wouldn't get deleted they'd continue generating views and possibly answer like I want to answer now.

---

I would like to propose for `Community` to be adjusted as it seems while trying to keep [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) clean, `Community` getting rid of legitimate questions and possibly future answers and preventing / denying community to grow, here is another one of my question that was closed and deleted and never reinstated even though I asked for it.

[I asked my question, yet it was closed and then deleted - Android Enthusiasts Meta Stack Exchange](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/i-asked-my-question-yet-it-was-closed-and-then-deleted)
[games - How to do "Android Party Play" with "Real Racing 3"? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120857/how-to-do-android-party-play-with-real-racing-3)

I have more examples to show, but I hope I'm getting my point across)

Thoughts?

Comment: Thought #1: As we cannot "adjust Community", shouldn't this question be moved to Meta.SE?

Answer (score 4):

The automated deleter is already very lenient, and only deletes questions which contain content that our contributors have shown aren't useful or relevant to the site. Both of the questions you link have a score of -1. Of the roughly 1000 people who saw each question, nobody thought they were "useful and clear", but at least one person thought they were "unclear or not useful". They were deleted after three to four months of inactivity.

To prevent your questions being deleted, you need to make them more useful, so that other people will vote them up and not down. In this particular case, asking a first question, and then when you found more information, you edited your first question to include "UPDATE" and a link to a new question, but no explanation of how the questions related or why you'd done this. If I had seen the two questions, I might have closed the second question as a duplicate of the first anyway. I think that might have caused the downvote in this case, but the misuse of `code formatting` in your questions might have contributed too. In general, the advice in [How do I ask a good question?](//android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) will help to make sure your questions don't get closed or downvoted, and consequently don't get automatically deleted as "not useful".

Beeshyams (one of our regular users, who often tries to help track down more complex problems) posted an answer on your second question, but you didn't upvote his answer or give him any feedback, so he deleted the answer himself three weeks later. If you found his answer useful, you could have voted it up, and that would have prevented your question being deleted. The system avoids deleting any content that anyone finds useful.

---

In summary: the deletion bot is called "Community" because it reflects the will of the site's community. If you write a question that the community finds useful, it won't be deleted. If someone puts the effort into trying to solve your problem, and that's useful, you need to show it by upvoting. Voting isn't just cosmetic, and it doesn't just give feedback to other people: it also controls the system, by showing it which content we want and which content we don't want.

Comment: +1  :  Well summarised and this sentence should go into help center IMO: *Voting isn't just cosmetic, and it doesn't just give feedback to other people: it also controls the system, by showing it which content we want and which content we don't want.*